# How to run Docker on RHEL 6.3 with kernel 2.6?

Tags: rhel, docker

Yes, it is an old platform and not supposed to work with Docker.

Please let me know if there is a workable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Docker 1.7 on a kernel 2.6.32-431 or higher but you need at least RHEL 6.6. According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/docker/installation/rhel/):

> Docker requires a 64-bit installation regardless of your Red Hat version. Docker requires that your kernel must be 3.10 at minimum. Red Hat 7 runs the 3.10 kernel, 6.6 does not. **We make an exception for Red Hat 6.6. To run Docker on Red Hat-6.6 or later, you need kernel 2.6.32-431 or higher.**